# Alignment issue and image hover effects problems in UC Browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, performance, hover, alignment

I am facing some alignment issue in UC BROWSER in mobile on rest of the browser it works fine except UC.

=> [Site looks something like this when opened on browsers like chrome, Mozilla, opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibmb4.png)

But if I open the same site in UC Browser of mobile then,

=> [As you can see this image the admission enquiry floating button is misaligned and the still state of images in UC Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JggZK.png)

Please do suggest any solution I am using css3 for these hover effects and rotate to the enquiry button

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me this browser doesn't support some (basic?) CSS3 features, like rotate.

I would redesign these parts as images, generally treating it like CSS2 for everything that doesn't look right.

Also, it is best if you posted some code so we could have a look for what's not working, as my answer is currently not much more than an educated guess.

Comment: perhaps, but not very likely. you'll have to try.